# How to find recurrence relation for $f(x)=x^3-\alpha=0$ where $\alpha>0$ using newton raphson method?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Alright for $x^3-\alpha=0$ we know that $x=\sqrt[3]\alpha$ is the root of course but unlike defined number it is too complicated to be solved using $x_0=\sqrt\alpha$ or $x_0=1$ for example so what is the idea behind it?

Comment: How about you solve $$\frac{1}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{\alpha}=0$$ or how about $$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x^{2}}{\alpha}=0$$ it is not hard to establish a recursive relation that converges fast to your desired precision

Comment: @GAUSS1860 oh I got it, seems I misunderstood the question. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=x^3-\alpha$ then the Newton Raphson method would give the recurrence relation $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^3-\alpha}{3x_n^2}$$